# Total elongation of combined wire

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

The question states :

Two thin wires $A$ and $B$ of equal length $L$ and equal cross sectional area $A$ and masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ are joined end to end and suspended.Wires $A$ and $B$ have Young's modulus $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ respectively.Find the total elongation in the combined rod .

My initial approach was to create a combined system with equivalent Young's modulus, taking the weight to be acting at the center of mass of the system and then solving it ,but I don't seem to arrive at the correct answer , is this approach wrong? Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: The given answer is [$M_1Y_2$+$M_2(Y_1+2Y_2)$]$g$$L$/$2$$AY_1Y_2$

Comment: There is no $M_1$ and $M_2$ in the question.

Comment: @Claudio Saspinski  sorry I have edited..it

Comment: @Claudio Saspinski  If you have a possible solution, please help

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is draw a simple free-body diagram to determine the tension in each string, using which you can calculate the corresponding elongation in the string (strain). Then add up the strains of each string for the total strain.

Comment: I think that elongation and strain are not synonyms. And, while you can add up elongations, the same does not work for strains.